# Always facing below error when trying to connect PowerApps with Microsoft Navision 2016

Tags: navision, powerapps

I am facing below error every time when I try to connect Navision 2016 with PowerApps.

Error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOp25.png

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct, some bits are missing!
Here is an example URL:
[http://servername:port/DynamicsNAV110/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20UK%20Ltd.')/ItemLedgerEntries](http://EVO-LPT054.evosoft.local:7702/DynamicsNAV110/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20UK%20Ltd.')/ItemLedgerEntries)